# How to login to a web application using python, when it is using salt validation?

Tags: python

I am having a tough time to login to a website that is protected by site. 
so far I am using the following code to accomplish my task:

```
res = requests.get('http://domain.com')
salt_value = re.search('name="salt".*value="(.*)"', res).group(1)
payload = {
    'username': 'test',
    'password': 'test12345678',
    'salt':'%s'%salt_value
}

res=requests.post('http://domain.com',data=payload)

print res.text
```

I am not getting the expected response. Please help.

Comment: What are you doing that regex search on? What makes you think you need to post a salt in the first place?

Comment: Please find an updated code above. I am first sending a request and then trying to search for salt value in its html source code to login further. I need to post salt value to login to my application. Do I clear myself? please let me know if you need any further information. thanks for your attention though :)

Answer (score 0):

First analyze connection between browser and server - for example using `Firebug` in Firefox.

Maybe you have to `GET`t page to get cookies before you use `POST`.
Maybe you have to send more data in `POST` - data from hidden fields.
Maybe you need correct `user-aget`.

Or maybe you use too greedy rexeg and your salt is incorrect.
Better use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to get element from HTML.